# How to use dataloader?

Tags: javascript, graphql, sequelize.js, dataloader

Im trying to figure this out.

I want to get all my users from my database, cache them
and then when making a new request I want to get those that Ive cached + new ones that have been created.

So far:

```
const batchUsers = async ({ user }) => {
  const users = await user.findAll({});

  return users;
};

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  playground: true,
  context: {
    userLoader: new DataLoader(() => batchUsers(db)),// not sending keys since Im after all users
  },
});
```

my resolver:

```
    users: async (obj, args, context, info) => {
      return context.userLoader.load();
}
```

load method requiers a parameter but in this case I dont want to have a specific user I want all of them.

I dont understand how to implement this can someone please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to just load all records, then there's not much of a point in utilizing DataLoader to begin in. The purpose behind DataLoader is to batch multiple calls like `load(7)` and `load(22)` into a single call that's then executed against your data source. If you need to get all users, then you should just call `user.findAll` directly.

Also, if you do end up using DataLoader, make sure you pass in a function, not an object as your context. The function will be ran on each request, which will ensure you're using a fresh instance of DataLoader instead of one with a stale cache.

```
context: () => ({
  userLoader: new DataLoader(async (ids) => {
    const users = await User.findAll({
      where: { id: ids }
    })

    // Note that we need to map over the original ids instead of
    // just returning the results of User.findAll because the
    // length of the returned array needs to match the length of the ids
    return ids.map(id => users.find(user => user.id === id) || null)
  }),
}),
```

Note that you could also return an instance of an error instead of `null` inside the array if you want `load` to reject.

Comment: Thanks for the explenation. Jump started my brain. I do realize that I chose a poor example with fetching all users. For clarity sake, would you mind adding an example where batching like you explain above would be useful. Again thanks alot!

Comment: Edited answer to include full example

Comment: Thank you! I was probably a bit unclear in the extra edit. Was hoping to see a scenario where you actually use the dataloader. My example with fecthing users was rather poor and was thinking perhaps you could share a scenario where you use it. Accepting the answer, if the extra request is not to much i would be greatful!

Answer (score 1):

Took me a while but I got this working:

```
const batchUsers = async (keys, { user }) => {
  const users = await user.findAll({
    raw: true,
    where: {
      Id: {
        // @ts-ignore
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        [op.in]: keys,
      },
    },
  });

  const gs = _.groupBy(users, 'Id');
  return keys.map(k => gs[k] || []);
};

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  schema,
  playground: true,
  context: () => ({
    userLoader: new DataLoader(keys => batchUsers(keys, db)),
  }),
});
```

resolver:

```
  user: {
    myUsers: ({ Id }, args, { userLoader }) => {
      return userLoader.load(Id);
    },
  },
```

playground:

```
{users
{Id
myUsers
{Id}}
}
```

playground explained:

users basically fetches all users and then myusers does the same thing by inhereting the id from the first call.

I think I choose a horrible example here since I did not see any gains in performence by this. I did see however that the query turned into:

```
SELECT ... FROM User WhERE ID IN(...)
```